# Finding fields for standard data types

Tags: data, schema, data-types

I've been trying to complete a challenge on trailhead ([link here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro?trailmix_creator_id=scabras&trailmix_slug=balance-developers-recruiting))

The text says
"Create an Apex trigger that sets an account’s Shipping Postal Code to match the Billing Postal Code if the Match Billing Address option is selected. Fire the trigger before inserting an account or updating an account. "

So I wrote this code:

```
trigger AccountAddressTrigger on Account (before insert, before update) {
    for (Account item : Trigger.new) {
        if (item.Match_Billing_address__c) {
            // ?
        }
    }
}
```

I tried looking up in the schema builder or anywhere really any information about what field to use in order to get the shipping and the billing postal code in order to update them but I couldn't find it anywhere.

I had to google the answer and found someone who suggested adding

```
item.ShippingPostalCode = item.BillingPostalCode;
```

My question is: Why? How do I know that ShippingPostalCode and BillingPostalCode are a thing?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Both fields are listed in the [Object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_account.htm) docs.

Comment: thank you @TSmith. Exactly what I was looking for. Is there any way to access the information from the object manager, schema builder or similar? Or do I always just refer to the docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will notice that these fields on Account (and other standard objects) are [compound fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields_address.htm). This means we cannot see the breakdown using Schema Builder but rather rely on the documentation (see [Account](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_account.htm) docs) and also page layouts if you really wanted to.